# Eclipse Luna error messages on GDB and Valgrind, unable to Debug or Profile C++ program as Local C/C++ Application

Tags: macos, gdb, valgrind, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-luna

I downloaded Eclipse Luna for 64-bit Mac OS X just a few days ago. Would like to use Eclipse for a small C++ program assigned as student homework. Set this up as an Eclipse C++ project.

I built the selected configuration as Debug and run it as Local C/C++ Application. All good. My C++ program runs and output appears in Console window exactly as I want it.

When I attempt *Debug as Local C/C++ Application* there is a message window `Error with command: gdb --version. Cannot run program 'gdb': Unknown reason.` So I am unable to launch my program in the Debug perspective and step-execute line by line, use breakpoints, examine variable assignments, etc.

When I attempt *Profile as Local C/C++ Application*, there is a message window `Couldn't determine version of Valgrind.` So I am unable to perform automated memory leak detection.

Do I need to complete my Eclipse installation in some additional way using Eclipse > Help > Install New Software option? Do I need to perform some additional installation(s) on my Mac that are outside of the Eclipse framework? I do not see what is missing here, as far as my software installations.

Any assistance, much appreciated..!

Properties for MyLittleProject, Tool Chain Editor
  Current toolchain: MacOSX GCC
  Current builder: Gnu Make Builder
  Used tools
MacOS X C Linker
MacOS X C++ Linker
GCC Assembler
GCC Archiver
GCC C++ Compiler
GCC C Compiler

ABOUT ECLIPSE
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
Build id: 20140612-0600

INSTALLATION DETAILS>>INSTALLED SOFTWARE
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
  EPP CPP Feature
     C/C++ Autotools support
     C/C++ Development Tools
        C/C++ Common GDB Support
        . . .
     C/C++ GCC Cross Compiler Support
     . . .
     CDT Standalone Debugger Support
     . . .
     GDB Tracepoint Analysis
     . . .
     Valgrind Tools Integration
        Profile Framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse can find neither *gdb* nor *valgrind* on your computer. You have to install these manually. You see at *INSTALLATION DETAILS>>INSTALLED SOFTWARE* that the interfaces to these two programs are installed, yet the programs themselves are missing.

On Mac, you may want to use *LLDB* instead of *gdb*.

If you insist on using the two, you have to install them first. I am not familiar with MacOS, but maybe the following links prove to be usefull:

- http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/
- http://calvinx.com/2014/05/04/valgrind-on-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks/

**Amendment:**
The valgrind plugin searches at a specific path for the binary. If it does not work, you need to add a symbolic link to the actual binary like so (from the [offical documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.linuxtools.valgrind.doc%2FLinux_Tools_Project%2FValgrind%2FUser_Guide%2FGeneral-Usage.html&cp=60_0_2_2&anchor=Other_Operating_Systems), note that there is a mistake which is corrected below):

```
ln -s $(which valgrind) /usr/bin/valgrind
```

Comment: I have gdb, and thanks to that "installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks" web page, I was able to use Eclipse Preferences to point to /usr/local/bin/gdb and now my Debug option is good. I installed valgrind and verified that I can run valgrind as expected from the Mac OS X Unix command line interface, but I cannot see any way to have Eclipse point to /usr/local/bin/valgrind when I want to "valgrind" my Eclipse C or C++ project. So Eclipse/valgrind, I am still "stuck".

Comment: The Eclipse plugin for valgrind seems to look for the valgrind binary at a specific path which cannot be configured. You need to add a symbolic link. I have update my answer.

Comment: Could you please check that? I have copied the command from the docs, but it seems somewhat queer. Maybe the argument should be the other way around: `ln -s $(which valgrind) /usr/bin/valgrind`

Comment: Thank you. After considering how a symbolic link is described, it looked to me like it should be "the other way around'. So I entered ln -s $(which valgrind) /usr/bin/valgrind and then I went to Eclipse and executed Profile As Local C/C++ Application and IT WORKS. This does valgrind for me right inside the Eclipse framework.

Comment: Thank you for reporting back. I have updated my answer. Could you accept the answer, so other people having the same problem may found this solution?

Comment: @jotrocken I have the same issue for 64-bit Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) on Linux. I guess the your fix should work for me as well, but I am not sure where exactly to add the symbolic link 
"ln -s $(which valgrind) /usr/bin/valgrind"
Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @BJPrim Sure: `ln -s TARGET LINK_NAME` links `TARGET` at the position `LINK_NAME`. Back when I wrote the answer, Eclipse searched for valgrind at `/usr/bin/valgrind`. However, the valgrind binary could be located at another directory, which you get by `which valgrind` (assuming valgrind is installed). The `$(COMMAND)` syntax executes a command and puts the output into the outer statement. If Eclipse Neon still has the same settings regarding the valgrind binary, the command above should still be fine. Does that help?