# Valgrind on Eclipse Luna with MacOS SIP

Tags: eclipse, macos, valgrind, eclipse-luna

I'm trying to use the Valgrind plugin on Eclipse Luna but Eclipse cannot find the location of the Valgrind binary.

[The Eclipse Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/Valgrind/User_Guide) and another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847091/eclipse-luna-error-messages-on-gdb-and-valgrind-unable-to-debug-or-profile-c) suggest creating the symbolic link:

`ln -s /usr/bin/valgrind /location/of/valgrind`

BUT ever since OS X El Capitan the system integrity protection (SIP) prohibit this action on `usr/bin`.

Has anyone found a way to use Valgrind in Eclipse with modern versions of OS X?

NOTE: my OS is Sierra 10.12.4, I DO have Valgrind installed in `/usr/local/bin`, and I am aware that Valgrind is not supported for this OS but I should still be able to tell Eclipse where to find the binary.

Comment: I think this is a pretty major problem with Linux Tools & Valgrind on MacOS Sierra and newer. There really should be a way to override the valgrind path within Linux Tools, since disabling SIP seems like a really bad idea. Also, Valgrind 3.13.0 does work with this OS - I think the support is a recent addition.

Answer (score 0):

There is a per-project workaround that seems to work. For example, if your installed valgrind binary is `/usr/local/bin/valgrind`:

- Open the project properties and select "Linux Tools Path",
- select "Prepend string to PATH" and choose "Custom",
- add the text `/usr/local/bin` to the text field.

This should enable the Linux Tools plugin to find the valgrind binary in /usr/local/bin.